# How to make puppeteer undetectable?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a supermarket website using puppeteer. I can scrape it using a chrome web scraper plugin though I would like the ability to do it programmatically. All I get is a blank screen and no content loads on the page.

I've tried all the tips and tricks around the web for making puppeteer undetectable and nothing has worked.  See below I have set a number of options that resemble a normal browser session though nothing seems to work.  Does anyone have any tips that can help me scrape this site?

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
    try {

        const args = [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--window-position=0,0',
            '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
            '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
            '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3312.0 Safari/537.36"'
        ];

        const options = {
            args,
            headless: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            userDataDir: './tmp',
            dumpio: true,
            devtools: true
        };

        //launch the browser
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

        //open new page
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        //set the browser viewport
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
        });

        //set the language to english
        await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            'Accept-Language': 'en'
        });
        //set the URL in a variable
        const url = 'https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/product/vanish-napisan-gold-pro-oxiaction';
        //Go to the page
        await page.goto(url, { "waitUntil": "networkidle2" });
        //get the title
        const productTitle = await page.$eval('span.product-name', el => el.innerText.trim());
        //log the title in the console
        console.log(productTitle);


    } catch (e) {
        console.log('our error', e);
    }

})();
```

What else should I try?

Answer (score 6):

It's posting to a fingerprint script.

So somehow you need to intercept that and change it.

[image: charles]

Comment: can you explain how we can intercept that?